# Env variable not being recognized

Tags: powershell, go, azure-devops

CICD: Azure devOps
Task: Azure CLI
Script Location: Inline Script
Task Version: 1
Agent: Self-hosted
Language: Go

I am facing a strange issue when I pass the env variable from Azure Pipeline.

**Command (Inline Script):-**

```
$env:ENV="FOO"
```

**Output:-**

```
2021-09-03T13:49:28.9213455Z 
2021-09-03T13:49:28.9214265Z c:\Agent\_work\r1\a>$env:ENV="FOO" 
**2021-09-03T13:49:28.9219788Z The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**
2021-09-03T13:49:28.9298991Z ##[error]Script failed with error: Error: The process 'c:\Agent\_work\_temp\azureclitaskscript1630676963575.bat' failed with exit code 1
```

The same command works perfectly fine in local VM PowerShell but not sure why it doesn't from Pipeline. Any suggestions?

Note: Directory path is correct ONLY.

Comment: You're writing PowerShell, but it's being executed as BATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $env:ENV="FOO"

This script is PowerShell Script.

You need to specify the use of PowerShell in the Azure CLI task to run the script.

In Azure CLI task V1 , it seems that there is no option to achieve this.

I suggest that you can use the Azure CLI task version 2:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xxx
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: '$env:ENV="FOO"'
```

[image]

Comment: Getting the following error "Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'powershell'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file."

Comment: @Learner. Are you using the Windows Agent or Linux Agent?

Comment: Using Windows self hosted agent. This works fine after choosing powershell core in 'Script Type' option.

Answer (score 2):

The script seems to be in `.bat` and `$env:ENV=...` is not a supported `bat` command.